# How to diagnose "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file" error?

Tags: windows, command-line, file-association

When running Python script at the command line I get this error

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You man not
>   have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

How can I check what path does the system try to access? No entries are created in any of system logs (Application, Security, Setup, System). All solutions which I found on the web mention changing file's properties. The problem is in this case I don't know what file the system tries to use to handle Python script. How can I find this information? I guess a tool which monitors all files the system tries to open might help here.

Details

When I try to run Python script with `.py` extenstion at the command line by just giving script's name (like `sample.py`) I get the above error. I guess the problem is due to bad file association but... running `reg query HKCR\.py /ve` gives `(Default)    REG_SZ    Python.File` and `reg query HKCR\Python.File\shell\open\command /ve` gives 
`(Default)    REG_SZ    c:\python\2.7\python.exe "%1" %*` and the file `c:\python\2.7\python.exe` exists and I can run it from command line without problem. This makes me think that system tries to open Python script using some other path in the registry. The problem is I have no idea what's this path.

Windows Vista 64bit, running 64bit cmd.exe, 64bit Python.

**EDIT**

Process Monitor is very helpful but I still can't find the exact root causing problem. Trying to launch Python script generates 866 entries:

```
BUFFER TOO SMALL                 1
END OF FILE                      1
FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS   12
NAME NOT FOUND                 301
NO MORE ENTRIES                  4
REPARSE                          5
SUCCESS                        542
```

There's no `NO SUCH FILE` result. I think it's because system doesn't even try to launch the executable to open Python file with due to not being able to find suitable registry entry defining handler for `.py` files. There are 178 entires of type `RegQueryKey` and 141 entries of type `RegQueryValue` but I have hard time trying to draw any conclusion reading them.

Comment: "NAME NOT FOUND" == "NO SUCH FILE"

Comment: If process monitor is showing entries for python.exe, then Python is definitely being launched.

Answer (score 3):

### A quick Process Monitor Primer

1. Open [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).
2. Run your application and wait for the error to happen.
3. Create a filter for your application, by right-clicking any of the entries that show the **Process Name** of your application and clicking **Include 'yourapp.exe'**.
   [image]
4. Now see what kinds of return values, you've gotten. Open the **Tools** menu and click **Count Occurrences**.
   [image]
5. In the **Column** field, select **Result** and hit **Count**.
   [image]
6. Now look for an error that could correlate to your problem.
   We have 2 **NO SUCH FILE** errors, that sounds interesting. Let's double-click on it!
7. And there we go...
   [image]